# Can't do anything in windows 8 store

Tags: windows-8, windows-update, windows-store

I got laptop with fresh install of windows 8 and want to update it to 8.1 before i start using it.
I installed two updates necessary to see update in store. Now i see update but when i click it, tile get's little smaller until I release a button but nothing else happens. The same with all other tiles(apps) in store. I got 19 updates in the corner but when i try that they all got stuck at "pending". Tried `WSReset.exe` - no luck

Comment: uninstall the other two updates.  Once that is done, install all updates, then try installing the Windows 8.1 update.  If that fails use the upgrade process.

Comment: Run the Windows Update troubleshooter: http://www.kapilarya.com/fix-windows-store-keep-pending-downloads-in-windows-8-1

Comment: installed all updates, now it works